# I'd like to create a view using multiple select statements that outputs multiple record sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I'd like to create a view using multiple select statements that outputs multiple record sets.

*For example.*

```
CREATE VIEW DBO.EXAMPLE1 
AS
SELECT * FROM BADGE WHERE BADGE.STATUS =1
SELECT * FROM EMP JOIN BADGE ON EMP.ID = BADGE.EMPID WHERE BADGE.STATUS =1
GO
```

I want output as follows:

```
ID  EMPID   STATUS
1   1        1
5   5        1
7   7        1
11  11       1
12  12       1

ID  LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME
1   Lake        Lisa
4   Mattil      Umar
5   Thottiyil   Khalid
87  Lal         NULL
7   shaikh      Nabil
```

Comment: A view is, by definition, a single select statement. If you need two statements, create two views. Alternatively, you can create a stored procedure with multiple result sets (although you can't interact with them very easily in SSMS)

Comment: On SO, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Answer (score 0):

A view can't return multiple record sets.  Only a stored procedure can do that.